# Electron package no window

Tags: electron

I run electron-packager to make a distributable from my app, but when I start the App.app, no window is shown, only the top menu.

Question: How do I best debug / troubleshoot this?

The app starts a web server and makes a tcp connection to another server. The html for the electron app is served from the local web server.

This is the output when building:

```
$ npx electron-packager ./ App --overwrite
Packaging app for platform darwin x64 using electron v1.8.4
Wrote new app to /Users/user/www/app/App-darwin-x64
```

I tried to run the node app manually in package, but got this:

```
$ cd App-darwin-x64/App.app/Contents/Resources/app/
$ npm start

electron not found
```

From package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.8.4",
    "electron-packager": "^12.0.1"
  },
```

---

```
$ node -v
v8.11.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run the app like that, you need to run it without the `Content/Resources/app`, as thats not where its stored. You need to run it from `App-darwin-x64/App.app`. You also don't call npm-start, as that's only called for running in dev.

Maybe try having a look at some example electron apps with build processes, try [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) as that has some good examples

Comment: That was just one of the ways I tried to troubleshoot why the window wasn't shown. Are there other ways? I noticed that when I run `App-darwin-x64/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App` from the terminal, I can see log output.

Comment: As stated, this problem has been solved many times before by electron-app boilerplates. I highly suggest using one as chances are, they've already solved the problems you're currently having